# How to gen an element of an html inside another html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have a code like below:

```
<a  href="modals/w4_ag_GiftServicesTemplate_MODAL_v1.html" >Activate Modal</a>
```

Now i want to get an element of the html (w4_ag_GiftServicesTemplate_MODAL_v1.html) within the calling html. Actually The href html will be displayed as Popup and I want to add a class on that html dynamically.

Comment: You should give an example of what you actually want to include in your page. Then, you should give some details. Is the target html under your control???

Answer (score 0):

First make an ajax request and get the contents of the second html page.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'ajax/test.html',
dataType: 'html',
success: function(data) {
  $('#html_content').html(data);
}
```

});

Now inside your html page include a div with id 'html_content'

```
<div id='html_content'></div>
```